# Ion exchange membrane that is dimensionally stable in organic solvents

Tags: materials

For an electrochemical flow cell stack employed in electrosynthesis, I require an proton exchange membrane (PEM) in order to enable "divided cell" electrolysis mode.

The Nafion proton exchange membrane that is currently used exhibits massive dimensional changes due to **swelling upon contact with organic solvents**, for example a length increase of close to 100% in Methanol, or 50% in Acetonitrile. These solvents are crucial for many experiments and thus cannot be avoided.

This dimensional change lead to failing seals between the gaskets and the membrane and thus to crossover of material between the anodic and cathodic compartments.

I'm thus looking for **alternatives to Nafion**, the requirements are as follows:

-swelling in the mentioned solvents <20%

-high conductivity

-commercially available (or otherwise sourceable)

Comment: Have you contacted the commercial producers? That would be my first step... This may well be closed as a "shopping question"...